# Copy files over WiFi less reliable than wired connection

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, file-transfer, wired-networking

I wan't to copy some data (2TB) from a network share to an external hard drive. My laptop is connected to the share using a WiFi connection. I don't care about the time it needs to copy. But is copying using a WiFi connection just as reliable than using a wired connection? Or should I just connect to the network using a cable?

Comment: Wifi uses a shared medium, therefore it is by definition not as reliable as a switched Ethernet connection. It the reliability difference has an effect for you depends on the used protocols and how they deal with network errors.

Comment: I would highly recommend using a cable considering the huge amount of data, speeds, stability, etc. Better be safe than sorry.

Comment: Is it also wise to first copy to local hard disk and than external drive? Or could I just copy straight to external drive?

Comment: There is no need to first copy the data to the local hard disk in the case of a simple copy operation. If there was involved some secondary temporary process that was applied on the data - maybe.

Comment: I have connected with a cable and currently copying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever medium you may be using, you should be specifying some kind of Verification Options. In the case of the Wireless Connections, it is highly recommended to turn them on somehow.

From the Command-Line, you should be searching for the switches that are enforcing the Verification Algorithms. For instance, in the *MicroSoft* *Windows* **10** Operating System Command-Line Preprocessor, you can use the following Operating System Commands and Switches:

[image: Operating System Command-Line Verification Commands and Switches]

From a File-Management Static Software Application such as GHISLER_Christian's *Total Commander* (that has its own Mobile counterparts even on the Tablet Personal Computer and on the SmartPhone), you should also search for such options:

[image: Total Commander Verification Option]

Errors may appear even on the Wired Connections. Turning on these Verification Options is always advisable when one is interested in the success of the Copy Operations.

Comment: I have total commander. Is that preferred over built-in copy command from Windows?

Comment: I guess that the `copy`, the `xcopy` and the `robocopy` Operating System Commands might be faster than _Total Commander_. But simply _Total Commander_ has a Graphical User Interface and it might help you in applying your choices. And it is also shareware.

Comment: If the connection is stable (does not drop) then the copy over wireless is as good as wired (in my experience myself and for clients)

Comment: I have connected with a cable and currently copying with Total Commander with the verify option enabled. Its slow but I don't mind.